# Is this transformation bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

> $T:P_2(x) \to P_3(x)$, where $T(p(x))=xp(x)$

So T can be written as $T(c+bx+ax^2) = (cx + bx^2 + ax^3)$

I'm finding it hard to see the one-to-one nature here, although I am pretty sure I saw in an earlier chapter in the book that it is one-to-one. Maybe I'm looking for a new perspective on how you show this here.I think I'm supposed to be looking at the coefficients and not the x's, is that correct?

For surjectivity, well if I look at the coefficients, $cx + bx^2 + a x^3$ is actually $0d + cx + bx^2 + ax^3$ so only these vectors in the whole of $P_3$ space is being mapped too, so it is not onto.

Any help on injectivity?

Comment: Just to be clear on surjectivity, can you mention one explicit element of $P_3$ that isn't mapped to?

Comment: hhhmmm, my knowledge is a little naive at the moment, but I suppose i could say there is nothing being mapped to any d. The $dim(P_3)$ = 4, so the the d element is not being mapped to.

Comment: ... unless $d = 0$. But yes, constant non-zero polynomials are not being mapped to. $1$ is a concrete example. Cool. One usually displays a concrete element like this as a "witness" against surjectivity, as well as some sort of proof or evidence that this concrete element is, in fact, not mapped to. It is often the easiest way to let others confirm that you are right, and often enough also the easiest proof of non-surjectivity to find and write.

Comment: Oh, yeah I didn't get it quite right. d = 0, not 0(d). Can you expand on what rldias has said @Arthur. I'm not exactly following the injectivity issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that $T$ is injective, given $p$ and $q$ in $P_2(x)$, we have to show that $T(p) = T(q)$ implies $p=q $ (it's equivalent to $p\neq q$ imply $T(p) \neq T(q)$).

So, let $p=c_1+b_1x+a_1x^2$ and $q=c_2+b_2x+a_2x^2$ and suppose 
$$T(p) = T(q).$$
Then
$$c_1x+b_1x^2+a_1x^3 = c_2x+b_2x^2+a_2x^3.$$
In other words (two polynomials are equal if they have the same coefficients)
$$c_1=c_2, \quad b_1=b_2, \quad a_1=a_2.$$
It means that $p=q$.

Comment: Hi @rldias. I probably need more explanation in words here, as I still cannot follow this. I'm a bit slow sometimes.

Comment: @Bucephalus What does injectivity mean to you?

Comment: Given $T:V \to W$, for every element $\text{v}$ in $\text{V}$ there is a mapping to a unique element $\text{w}$ in $\text{W}$. Therefor $\text{dim(V)} \ge \text{dim(W)}$.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: I think I'm getting it now. From calculus, no polynomial function of the same order can have the same y value given the same x, unless each of those functions have the same coefficients, i.e. are one and the same function. So  given the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ it is the coefficients that differentiates all of the functions in this vector space.

Comment: This probably seems obvious to you I suppose. Thanks for your help @rldias.

Comment: In your question, you've asked: "I think I'm supposed to be looking at the coefficients and not the x's, is that correct?" It's absolutely right. We are interested only in the coefficients -- the coefficients are the ID of a polynomial, and we want to look at two polynomials in order to know if they're the same one.

Comment: Good thankyou @rldias